# JBPM 6 Process Image REST

Tags: jbpm

I am using JBPM 6.1.0.Final deployed on jboss as 7.

I want to get a list of all the process images for all my deployed processes.

Is is possible to get the process image through the REST API and if not can I get it any other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as my research goes, It does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The REST call is supported for the 6.3 according this official changelog:
https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch25.html